# Python copy file to remote

Tags: python, linux, file-transfer

I am using this code

```
tar zcf - somefolder/ | ssh user@server "cd /path/to/remote && tar zxf -"
```

to copy files between 2 system

i want to do it in python

i did

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen('tar zcf - somefolder/ | ssh user@server "cd /path/to/remote && tar zxf -')
```

i also tried

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["tar","-zcf somefolder | ssh ubuntu@192.168.100.110 /path/to/remote && tar -zxf"])
```

but both not working
i also tried with run instead of popen but still not working

but

```
 stream = os.popen("cmd")
```

this is working fine but problem is i am not getting status

in first methods i can use

```
 os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)
```

to get live status of process

what i want is transfer files between remote and local without using external libraries
and with live status

how can i achive this?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple and use the os module, which is also faster than subprocess:

`result = os.popen("command").read()`

Comment: how can i get status in this method?

Comment: @Harishuw using this command will force the program to wait until the command is finished. There is no need to check the status. When the result is ready the command is done.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I overlooked "no external module" sorry. But maybe it's useful for others searching.

There is a module for that :)

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('example.com')

# SCPCLient takes a paramiko transport as an argument
scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())

scp.put('test.txt', 'test2.txt')
scp.get('test2.txt')

# Uploading the 'test' directory with its content in the
# '/home/user/dump' remote directory
scp.put('test', recursive=True, remote_path='/home/user/dump')

scp.close()
```

Or with usage of `with`:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient

with SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.connect('example.com')

    with SCPClient(ssh.get_transport()) as scp:
        scp.put('test.txt', 'test2.txt')
        scp.get('test2.txt')
```

See: https://pypi.org/project/scp/

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, using `subprocess.run()` to run an external Ubuntu program/process I've had to use each command parameter or such as a different list entry, like so:

`subprocess.run(['pip3', 'install', 'someModule'])`

So maybe try putting every single space-separated argument as it's own list element.